# how to i create an imageurl link to sql database in mvc4

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

hi guys how to i able to insert imageurl into database? after i insert into my database , my imageurl row appears to be NULL.

```
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageURL { get; set; }
```

my question.cshtml

```
<tr>
        <td  colspan="3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageURL)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageURL, new { type = "file", id="fileupload", name="fileupload" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageURL)
            <img src="#" id="imgThumbnail" alt="preview" width="10%" height="15%" />
        </td>
```

my controller

```
foreach (QuestionVM0 q1 in qo)
            {

                int aID = question1.ActivityID.Value;

                string sImageURL = q1.ImageURL.ToString();



                Models.question1 questionCreate = new question1();

                questionCreate.ImageURL = sImageURL;
                db.questions1.Add(questionCreate);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Entity Framework model should have a `byte[]` property mapped to a `varbinary(max)` column in your database. It appears that currently you have defined it as a string which is wrong. So:

```
public class question1 
{
    public byte[] ImageURL { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And then read from the HttpPostedFileBase property on your view model and copy it to the `byte[]` property on your EF model:

```
foreach (QuestionVM0 q1 in qo)
{
    int aID = question1.ActivityID.Value;

    byte[] imageData = null;
    using (MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream())
    {
        q1.ImageURL.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
        imageData = target.ToArray();
    }

    Models.question1 questionCreate = new question1();
    questionCreate.ImageURL = imageData;
    db.questions1.Add(questionCreate);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

---

UPDATE:

It appears that you want to store only the location of the file in the database and not the file itself. In this case you should do this:

```
foreach (QuestionVM0 q1 in qo)
{
    int aID = question1.ActivityID.Value;

    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(q1.ImageURL.FileName);
    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
    q1.ImageURL.SaveAs(path);

    Models.question1 questionCreate = new question1();
    questionCreate.ImageURL = path;
    db.questions1.Add(questionCreate);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: hi but my database table is varchar(255) , i cant usevarbinary(max), i just want to store the url link to database lol

Comment: Then you should store the uploaded file somewhere on the file system and then only store the path to this file in your database. I have updated my answer to illustrate how you could achieve that.